# Parallels between Buddhist karma and Western philosphy?

Tags: buddhism

I feel there are some (re-)explorations in philosophy which are renditions of previously explored themes in the east.

Intuition Pumps and Other Tools for Thinking by Daniel Dennett (1995). In this book, Dennett argues that abstraction is an essential tool for learning and survival. He writes,

> "We learn from situations by abstracting patterns from them. This is
> necessary because the same situation never repeats itself exactly.
> There are always some differences. But if we can identify the patterns
> that are common to many situations, then we can learn from those
> patterns and use them to predict and control future events." (page 13)

In Buddhism, I subscribe to a similar idea of karma(/patterns). Hofstadter concretizes the idea of karma(/patterns) as recursions in Godel, Escher and Bach. Interestingly, he acknowledges there is one system which can always exit recursions which is the human.

But in Buddhism we would rather say something like you choose your karma (you enter a different recursive system). You never really exit the system of karma (not even in death). You merely choose a different set of karma. More appropriately one can [transform karma into mission](https://www.sokaglobal.org/resources/study-materials/buddhist-study/the-wisdom-for-creating-happiness-and-peace/chapter-12-4.html) (I wouldn't recommend a direct literal reading of the article).

> Whatever a person’s karma may be, it definitely has profound meaning.
> This is not just a matter of outlook. Changing the world starts by
> changing our fundamental state of mind. This is a key Buddhist
> principle. A powerful determination to transform even negative karma
> into mission can dramatically transform the real world. By changing
> our inner state of mind, we can change any suffering or hardship into
> a source of joy, regarding it as a means for forging and developing
> our lives. To turn even sorrow into a source of creativity—that is the
> way of life of practitioners of Nichiren Buddhism.

I was wondering if there were western philosophers as well who had parallels to the final viewpoint on the relation of karma/patterns/recursion to human well-being?

Comment: Since you juxtapose 'karma' with 'western' as contrasting terms, a comment: The *word* 'karma' is of course not to be found in the Bible (Torah,Koran), since Sanskrit and these scriptures were disjoint at the time. However if we take *As you sow, you shall reap* as the essential  idea of karma, you'll find it all over the Bible: https://bible.knowing-jesus.com/topics/Sowing-And-Reaping, particularly the NT selections

Comment: @Rusi in Nichiren Buddhism, one does not see karma as in certain versions of Hinduism: "an inevitable consequence of actions."  Instead causes do have effects but we are always in a position to create value.

Comment: Of course karma has various shades: in 'sow' there is agency, active role, whereas in 'reap' we (more) passively accept. More generally, karma and dharma are 2 key ontologies in the Indic religions, of which dharma — inner law — is where we have choice and agency, whereas karma — outer or given law — is about acceptance to what is with good grace

Comment: Yes, in Buddhism it is different: "But Nichiren Buddhism teaches that we can change all such karma. We can transform even fixed karma—or rather, we must do so. No matter what sufferings or hardships we may encounter, we must live out our lives fully, fighting our hardest until we triumph. Those who win in the end are true victors in life." + https://www.sokaglobal.org/resources/study-materials/buddhist-study/the-wisdom-for-creating-happiness-and-peace/chapter-8-7.html